# Swap characters from odd positions with even positions in a string

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Having the following input:

1. The input string in `RDI`
2. The input size of the string in `RDX`,

and the output string in `RSI`,

I want to swap the even-positioned caharacters with odd-positioned ones.

Example:

*Input*: **airport 7**

*Output*: **iaprrot**

Comment: `rsp` is not a general purpose register. You may be able to treat it as such locally, but what was there on entry must be preserved, somehow, otherwise `ret` will go to a random place.

Comment: That issue aside, if you are free to use any method you like, my suggestion would be to read two characters at a time as long as there are two available, and then swap them, as in `mov AX, [RDI]; XCHG AL, AH; mov [RSI], AX`.

Comment: It would be vastly simpler to copy two bytes at once, swapping the pair.  Look at how much logic you need to figure out exactly what to do with a single position.  (Especially if you insist on inc/dec of registers instead of just using an offset in the addressing mode.)  e.g. `movzx eax, word [rdi[` / `rol ax, 8` (swap AH and AL) / `mov [rsi], ax`

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Heh, we were both the same comment at the same time.  But note that `rol ax, 8` is more efficient than `xchg`, especially if you want to read the AX afterward.  (No partial-register merging needed.)

Comment: but what is wrong with my code/logic basically? I'm very trivial in this assembly stuff and so wouldn't know how to apply what you guys said.

Comment: I'm not sure anything *is* wrong with your logic, except for destroying the stack pointer so `ret` will try to pop a return address from an invalid pointer.  Pick any other register, then use a debugger (GDB for example) to single-step your code.  "plenty of errors" is not specific enough for a [mcve], so if you want other people to help debug, make sure you quote error messages, and/or exact results of what does happen, and what you see with a debugger.

Comment: no way, you were totally right with the RSP, that was the problem. But now I see it doesn't add the last character from the string. so like the output size is inputsize-1

Comment: The problem with overwriting RSP is almost a duplicate of [Why are rbp and rsp called general purpose registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36529449).  If you want help debugging your messy logic for the final character, fix that bug (in the question) so it's not a distraction, and include that specific actual result in the question.  Then ideally also update with what you find while single-stepping that last iteration.  (Or maybe you'll notice on your own if something's wrong with your logic)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Even more efficient would be doing multiple pairs of bytes at once.  e.g. `(x & 0x00ff00ff...) << 8 | ((x>>8) & 0x00ff00ff...)`.  Up to 8 bytes at a time in scalar registers.  Or get the masking for free with SSE2 (baseline for x86-64) `psrlw` / [`psllw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psllw:pslld:psllq), doing 16 bytes at a time.  (Or 8 or 4 with movq / movd loads/stores.  Obviously even more efficient if you have SSSE3 `pshufb` to re-arrange byte in one instruction.

Comment: @thebalkandude: Where is the final byte supposed to come from, in odd-length strings?  Are you supposed to copy the unpaired byte from the *same* position?  Because copying from one byte later would mean you load the terminating 0 byte of the source string.  If so, the final byte will need special handling whether you do it efficiently (1 pair at a time) or not.

Comment: Related: [Reverse byte order in XMM or YMM register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56407741) mentions using `pshufb` to swap bytes within 16-bit words.  But the answer's mostly about reversing whole arrays.  [What is the fastest way to swap the bytes of an unaligned 64 bit value in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62376832) has a `pshufb` answer which can work for 16-bit elements as well as 32 and 64-bit elements.  [Trying to convert big to little endian with x86 asm SSSE3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52054144) has actual shuffle-control constants.